# Issue of structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

"structure of query does not match function result type" this isssue occurred when i try to execute the this function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION historicalavg01() RETURNS SETOF text AS
$$
DECLARE starttime timestamp;
DECLARE endtime timestamp;
DECLARE total_hour_avg DOUBLE PRECISION;
l_row RECORD;
BEGIN
CREATE TEMP TABLE historical_temp(Histroical DOUBLE PRECISION,time timestamp);
total_hour_avg := 0;
FOR b IN 0 .. 23 LOOP
    FOR a IN 0 .. 27 LOOP

        starttime := (CURRENT_DATE - (a  * INTERVAL '1 day')) + (b * INTERVAL '1 hour');

        endtime := (CURRENT_DATE - (a  * INTERVAL '1 day')) + ((b + 1) * INTERVAL '1 hour');

        total_hour_avg := total_hour_avg + (SELECT Avg("activepower") AS "Avg" FROM sca_meter WHERE "time" between starttime AND endtime);

        IF(a = 27) THEN 
            INSERT INTO historical_temp SELECT AVG(total_hour_avg) AS "Histroical Avg", CURRENT_DATE - ((b + 1) * interval '23 hour') AS "time";
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM historical_temp;

END$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT * FROM historicalavg01();
```

Please give the solution for it. thanks in adavance.

Comment: The `declare` keyword is only needed once, not for every variable declaration

Answer (score 1):

To return a TABLE add the table definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION historicalavg01() 
RETURNS TABLE
(
    Hist double precision,
    Tm   timestamp
) AS
$$
DECLARE starttime timestamp;
DECLARE endtime timestamp;
DECLARE total_hour_avg DOUBLE PRECISION;
l_row RECORD;
BEGIN
CREATE TEMP TABLE historical_temp(Histroical DOUBLE PRECISION,time timestamp);
total_hour_avg := 0;
FOR b IN 0 .. 23 LOOP
    FOR a IN 0 .. 27 LOOP

        starttime := (CURRENT_DATE - (a  * INTERVAL '1 day')) + (b * INTERVAL '1 hour');

        endtime := (CURRENT_DATE - (a  * INTERVAL '1 day')) + ((b + 1) * INTERVAL '1 hour');

        --total_hour_avg := total_hour_avg + (SELECT Avg("activepower") AS "Avg" FROM sca_meter WHERE "time" between starttime AND endtime);
        total_hour_avg := b * 0.5;

        IF(a = 27) THEN 
            INSERT INTO historical_temp SELECT AVG(total_hour_avg) AS "Histroical Avg", CURRENT_DATE - ((b + 1) * interval '23 hour') AS "time";
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM historical_temp;

END$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT * FROM historicalavg01();
```

> ```
> hist | tm                 
> :--- | :------------------
> 0    | 2020-02-05 01:00:00
> 0.5  | 2020-02-04 02:00:00
> 1    | 2020-02-03 03:00:00
> 1.5  | 2020-02-02 04:00:00
> 2    | 2020-02-01 05:00:00
> 2.5  | 2020-01-31 06:00:00
> 3    | 2020-01-30 07:00:00
> 3.5  | 2020-01-29 08:00:00
> 4    | 2020-01-28 09:00:00
> 4.5  | 2020-01-27 10:00:00
> 5    | 2020-01-26 11:00:00
> 5.5  | 2020-01-25 12:00:00
> 6    | 2020-01-24 13:00:00
> 6.5  | 2020-01-23 14:00:00
> 7    | 2020-01-22 15:00:00
> 7.5  | 2020-01-21 16:00:00
> 8    | 2020-01-20 17:00:00
> 8.5  | 2020-01-19 18:00:00
> 9    | 2020-01-18 19:00:00
> 9.5  | 2020-01-17 20:00:00
> 10   | 2020-01-16 21:00:00
> 10.5 | 2020-01-15 22:00:00
> 11   | 2020-01-14 23:00:00
> 11.5 | 2020-01-14 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4b9ec75269ea6f729b2d63af6eb33ee8)*

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/) about it.

Comment: I guess the correct answer depends on what OP wants, which we do not know. Prehaps the query result should be formatted as a string?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you're right, I'll wait for OP explanations.

Comment: @McNets thanks lot, issue resolved.